# Bootstrap image on the left of an entire div

Tags: bootstrap-4, css-float

So I would like to obtain something like this (where the image is on the left of the text):

Note when you run the example please open it with "full page"

```html
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
       </div>
      <div class="col-11">
       <h1>some title</h1><p>Some Paragrah</p><p>Other Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If you open this example full page you will notice there is some margin between the image and the rest of the content.
I would like **to have no margin** between the image and the text on the right.

How can I do it ?

I have tried float-left, but with float the text that overflow the height goes under the image and i want to keep all the text on right.

### Desired output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself since I think i found an easier solution: just use `.no-gutters` to remove any margin between cols:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
       </div>
      <div class="col-11">
       <h1>some title</h1><p>Some Paragrah</p><p>Other Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Bootstrap-4, how about using `flex` classes for your use case...

**working snippet** below:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex mb-3">
    <div class="p-2 ">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 ">
      <h1>some title</h1>
      <p>Some Paragrah</p>
      <p>Other Paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks akber ! are there any other official way of doing it ? I mean at the end is just an image that must be on the left on an entire div

Comment: images usually have `img-fluid` class on them, to ensure no overlap...